# Iptcinfo3 error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535

Tags: python, metadata

I'm trying to change metadata of files with `iptcinfo3` but sometimes I get `error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535` error at the line #1 when I'm trying to save it.

```
def changefiletags(filename,tags):
    info = iptcinfo3.IPTCInfo(filename)
    info['keywords'] = tags
    info.save() #1
    os.remove(filename+ '~')
```

How to avoid this?
by the way error full text:

```
  File "F:\projects\pic downloader\sourcecode\imagedownloader2.py", line 44, in changefiletags
    info.save()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\iptcinfo3.py", line 627, in save
    return self.save_as(self._filename, options)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\iptcinfo3.py", line 670, in save_as
    data = self.photoshopIIMBlock(adobe, self.packedIIMData())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\iptcinfo3.py", line 940, in photoshopIIMBlock
    out.append(pack("!H", len(resourceBlock) + 2))  # length

error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback. A wild guess is that something with a 16-bit "length" field has got too large.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but sometimes I get error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535 error at the line #1 when I'm trying to save it." Okay, so what is your *question* about this? Did you try to figure out what the `number` is that it's complaining about? Did you try to figure out what the value of the `number` is? Did you expect to be able to use a value outside that range? If so, why? If not, then the problem is that the value is outside of that range, and should not be outside of that range. Right? So - why is it outside of that range?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and work backwards to understand where the bad data comes from. If you cannot solve the problem yourself, [even with your best effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), then show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that lets us see the problem, along with the [exact, complete, corresponding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message - copied and pasted, starting from `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue?